# Why Integer Morph Map in Laravel 8 not work

Tags: php, laravel, migration, polymorphism, laravel-8

I create something like below for morph map:

```php
        Relation::morphMap([
            0 => User::class,
            1 => UserType::class,
            2 => Address::class,
            3 => Application::class,
        ])
```

in `AppServiceProvider` but when i used in seeder for `UserType`, it shows me following error:

```
 General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'user_types' for column 'metable_type' at row 1
```

Answer (score 2):

;)
Just start with 1 not zero like following:

```php
        Relation::morphMap([
            1 => User::class,
            2 => UserType::class,
            3 => Address::class,
            4 => Application::class,
        ])
```

Comment: What a joke! I wonder what the reason for this is. Does this method treat sequential arrays and assoc. arrays differently? Anyway, you saved me a lot of head scratching

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my last few projects i wonder to use numbers instead of the string, it works like you mentioned, i were starting with zero every time that's why i didn't have any result (:.